# Highlight correct answers in a quiz app

Tags: java, android

Good day guys. I have a multiple choice quiz app with 4 choices. Question and score  are automatically updated onclick of any button. There is no "next" button. 
I tried to add this code ***"answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);"*** to highlight the correct answers onclick but the problem is, the highlighted button does not disappear when the next question is displayed. Please help.

```
public class SetA extends AppCompatActivity {
....
private TextView mScore;
private TextView mQuestion;
private Button mBtn1;
private Button mBtn2;
private Button mBtn3;
private Button mBtn4;
private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionNumber = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seta);
........

    mScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
    mQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
    mBtn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    mBtn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    mBtn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice3);
    mBtn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice4);
    mQuestions.initQuestions(getApplicationContext());
    updateQuestion();
    updateScore(mScore);
}
private void updateQuestion(){
    if(mQuestionNumber<mQuestions.getLength() ){

 mQuestion.setText(mQuestions.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));

 mBtn1.setText(mQuestions.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 1));

 mBtn2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 2));

 mBtn3.setText(mQuestions.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 3));


 mBtn4.setText(mQuestions.getChoice(mQuestionNumber,4));
        mAnswer = mQuestions.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }
    else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(SetA.this, Scores.class);
        intent.putExtra("score", mScore);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
private void updateScore(int point) {
    mScore.setText(""+mScore+"/"+mQuestions.getLength());
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    Button answer = (Button) view;
    if (answer.getText().equals(mAnswer)){
answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        mScore = mScore + 1;
        Toast.makeText(SetA.this, "Correct!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else
        Toast.makeText(GESetA.this, "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    updateScore(mScore);
    updateQuestion();
}
....
```

Comment: Please explain which button do you want to hide ?

Comment: i want to restore the color of all buttons because when it is highlighted, it remains highlighted in the next questions.

Comment: set the button background color to default when loading the next question.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the background color when you update the next question:

```
answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this out for myself, but I don't see anywhere where you change the colour back. If you highlight the button to be green on correct answer then you'd need code that reset the colour when the next question is chosen.

You'd need to implement something that knows that you've selected it and then moved to the next question. Sorry if this seems vague but I'm trying to explain it as best I can.

Basically, right now the part that highlights the questions have no way of knowing that the question has moved to a new question, and you need to implement something like that. Probably something like this psuedocode:

```
if(question is next question){restore default colours;}
```

Something like that. Obviously that's just a real basic psuedocode. If you require more substantial help I'll take another look at it a bit later on today and actually test out the app for myself and see what I can come up with.

Comment: thank you very much for answering. I will try your idea.

Comment: No problem. Best of luck! Let me know if you need any more help and I'll try and do what I can.